# Web Scraping with Nokogiri::HTML and Ruby - How do you handle when what you are looking for isn't there?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, web-scraping

I've got a script that works for 99% of the pages I want to scrape but just a few of them don't have what I am looking for and my script errors out with a

```
undefined method `attribute' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The code is a bit ugly from fiddling around and debugging but here is what I am doing. The error is on the third line and is simply because in the error cases there is no .entry-content img:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
image_link = doc.css(".entry-content img")
temp = image_link.attribute('src').to_s
```

How can I detect this and handle the error when the image_link returned by Nokogiri isn't nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
if image_link = doc.at_css(".entry-content img")
  temp = image_link['src']
else
  # Whatever else
end
```

Alternatively, you could use an XPath selector to get the attribute value directly:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div class="entry-content"><img src="bar"></div>')
src = doc.at_xpath('//*[@class="entry-content"]//img/@src').to_s
# src is "bar"; if the html didn't have such an item, it would be "" (nil.to_s)
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  I had tried it but the nodeset returned from nokogiri isn't nil.

Comment: @srboisvert My apologies; I forgot to change `css` (which returns an empty Nodeset for no matches) to `at_css` (which returns `nil`). I've edited the answer with this change. However, I believe you are wrong about the Nodeset. For me, `doc.css("foo bar").empty? #=> true`.

Comment: Actually I think empty? method of Nodeset does the trick.  You didn't give me the answer but you did unclog my brain clot.  Thanks.